# Pass method to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

In Javascript I'm trying to pass a class member to a jQuery function, but somehow the 'this' object in that function gets messed up. This is the code:

```
function Hints() 
    {
    this.markProduct = function() { alert('hi'); };
    this.selectProduct = function() { this.markProduct(); }; 
    }
```

When I call this code using this:

```
oHints = new Hints();
oHints.selectProduct();
```

It works just fine and the 'this' object in the 'selectProduct' function refers to the Hints object.
But when I try this:

```
oHints = new Hints();
$('#prodquery').keydown(oHints.selectProduct);
```

The 'this' object in the 'selectProduct' function refers to the html object that fired the keydown event.

Does anyone have a clue? I'm puzzled :/

Comment: Just to be picky... JS does not have classes, it has prototypes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
$('#prodquery').keydown(function() { oHints.selectProduct() });
```

And then [read this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) for explanation of how `this` works in different contexts.